# Как защитить php скрипт от копирования?

Tags: php

Я переделал немного дизайн и функционал у скрипта. Хотелось бы закодировать его.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, простые и не сложные программы для кодировки с русской инструкцией?

Answer (score 1):

1. [выбирайте](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&q=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B+php&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)
2. [читаем](http://habrahabr.ru/post/140159/)